# Setting value of an input hidden field on .aspx page from a user control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events

Could please anyone tell me how can I set an input hidden field value which is on my .aspx page, from a user control? This user control has couple of drop downs and I can create `OnClientSelectedIndexChanged` JavaScript event handler in my user control but can't figure it out how to set the value in the hidden field which I have on my .aspx page. In other words my .aspx page is rendering this user control and I want to access .aspx page input field from the user control's `OnClientSelectedIndexChanged` JavaScript event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TagFilterComboBox_OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, args) {
     $(document).ready(function () {
         document.getElementById('<%=hiddenValidation.ClientID%>').value = "Something Changed";
      });
   }
</script>
```

I have tried this but it can't find the hiddenfield and getting:

> "Unknown Entity"

warning

I have added this JavaScript on my `UserControl` and `hiddenValidation` is my hidden field on my .aspx page. I am accessing this control on client side. In fact my Form is not validating the drop down boxes and to overcome this problem I am setting a string value to the input hidden field.

Comment: @user1273701 what is the `id` of your hidden input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `OnClientSelectedIndexChanged` function:

```
document.getElementById('yourHiddenID').value = 'whatever you want';
```

As a side note, you should bind your javascript functions in javascript, not using the markup properties of the control.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but it can't find the hiddenfield. I have added the code and some comments for clerity.

Comment: I have got it working by replacting ('<%=hiddenValidation.ClientID%>') with ('MainContent_hiddenValidation'). Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if your problem is to access the hidden control in aspx on the client side or the server side.

if on the client side you can write a javascript to `OnClientSelectedIndexChanged` and update the hidden field of ASPX, all ASCXs part of an ASPX becomes one DOM when it is rendered to the client(browser)

the control names will be prefixed with your ascx tag name and identifier so you might need to use the `ClientID` to get the id of a control.

on the server side on a postback you can get the values of aspx using the Request.Form, whenever a postback happens all the values of the control are passed in Request.Form collection.